# Verify minimum version requirements with bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

I maintain a gem with dependencies that are stored in a `Gemfile`, for example:

```
gem 'foo', '~> 1.5'
gem 'bar', '~> 2.0.5'
```

Thanks to [pessimistic version constraints](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74), bundler will by default install the *latest* `1.x` version of `foo`, but can compromise on a lower version if my gem is used in conjunction with another that requires (for example) `foo =1.6.2`

Question: Is there a simple way to get bundler to install all of the *minimum* versions of my dependencies (in this case, `foo =1.5.0` and `bar =2.0.5`) so that I can test whether, after I write some new functionality, my gem will still work in combination with other environments that use those lower versions?

Or, is the only way for me to manually reinstall all of the minimum versions and then run my tests?

Comment: Or do you mean you want to test without changing your gemfile?

Comment: @AlexPeattie yeah, conceptually the version dependencies aren't changing, I just want to *install* the lowest applicable rather than the highest

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it would be to override `Gem::Version.<=>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we decided to use Rubygems' Requirement class, there isn't a way to specify the lowest version. I vaguely recall an automated testing tool to help you iterate over dependency versions that you want to test against, but it's extremely hard to automate because there are an exponential number of possible version combinations. I suggest creating a second Gemfile with the oldest versions you want to test against, and using BUNDLE_GEMFILE to run against that Gemfile in an additional CI build.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question in IRC... from my understanding, there's no way to do it without changing your Gemfile. Sorry. :(

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb for reference